# updating plist file on launch of application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, resources, plist, viewdidload

I have an app that reads in a plist file from the resources folder. I have looked for about 5 hours for a solution to hosting my plist file on my freewebs acount and have the application update the plist file on launch. Can anyone help me please.
I will post my code if you ask. I am just not sure what you need to see now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Simple FTP Sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) for iPhone, on the apple developer site that may help.

and

[CFFTPStreamRef](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html)  reference, which  also links to other guides.

Comment: Thanks for the links. But I am very new to iphone programming and had done a tutorial program where there are three buttons you can tap. read documents, read web, read bundle, and each would either read a text file from the application bundle, read it from the documents folder of the app, or read a txt from a url upone being tapped. Is there a simple way to go about it like this? I just am not very good at writing my own methods and stuff from the examples given in the documentation.

Comment: I think anyone who is going to help you can only give you an example.
Which may be hard for you to adapt into your own code without some basic understanding on your part. I think you need to try and get a handle on reading the Developer Documentation. The more you read it, the more it will make sense.
Some of it has examples and points to companion programming guides and refs.

Re-reading your post,I think you want to read/write to a plist file on your web space rather than in the resources folder.Not backup. Is that right. If so, are you trying some sort of syncing ??

Answer (score 0):

You may already have this question answered but I would recommend you take a look at **[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** to download the data in a async fashion when your app loads. You can then very easily download that retrieved file into a local plist and save it to your documents folder.